# Dynamically receive component by AJAX with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I would like to create a dashboard with widgets. The user has the choose among a large list of widgets, but I don't want to load all the widgets in the browser's memory. Instead I would like to load the component dynamically over AJAX once a widget is added to the dashboard.

Is this something possible with Vue.js?

Comment: [Something like this](https://vuejsdevelopers.com/2017/10/30/vue-js-dynamic-imports-lazy-load/) ?

Comment: yup. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#Async-Components

Comment: @JacobGoh That's the name I was looking for `async components`, not `dynamic` ones.